# Is there an enterprise service or native method that provides remote disable for Linux laptops for corporate IT? Like jamf but for Linux

Tags: linux, security, remote-management

I'm trying to work with our IT to provide a Linux option for laptops. The main sticking point is the ability for IT to disable the possibility for anyone to login to the machine in the event of a lost or stolen device or an employee termination. Jamf provides minimal Linux coverage. Anyone know of an equivalent to Jamf for Linux out there?

Engineers are all 100% remote. AD is implemented using Azure AD (I think). People with windows machines are authed through AD, I believe. Mac folks are managed by Jamf and each engineer with a mac has a single account on the machine and they have sudo privs on their respective machines. Jamf provides the requirements as stated where IT can disable the machine when desired. I know that Linux can integrate with AD of old, but I'm not so sure about AD in azure. I'll start looking that up.

So to answer a few questions in comments...

1. I'm not shopping. I am seeking advice as this type of service seems to be lacking for Linux and perhaps I'm wrong. I'm wondering if anyone else has solved this problem and if so, how so?
2. I'm just one of the engineers attempting to assist the IT dept because I freakin hate macs and windows. So if I can find a way to solve this problem then we will be authorized to use Linux.
3. No VPN required and I don't think it would solve the ask. Again, the idea is to minimize the ability for an attacker (insider or otherwise) to use the machine as a vector of attack by the push of a button.

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: Well how does login work for your org? Because if it's like corporate linux laptops I've seen, the authentication is done against a server of your IT department. User gone – just disable his login entry there. Laptop stolen – don't allow said mashine to authenticate users. There's no "enterprise service" you'd need for that. Just as with Active Dir of the Windows ecosystem (which by the way does work for linux, as well), this is built-in, by the sheer principle of how login works.

Comment: If the machine connects to the VPN after boot without login, great, it identifies itself correctly to a VPN service. So, use your IT's local ssh-capable account to login into the machine and render it useless, in case its user said it was stolen.

Answer (score 1):

Any MDM solution might help - Intune or something similar.

But in my honest opinion I would use EDR (Endpoint Detection and Response tool) that your Security team might already be using. They support major OS versions and have a ton of control over Linux - things like remote isolate host, remote swipe, collect or deploy packages etc.

Comment: Lemme check into this. If it solves our problem, I'll score this as the answer! Thank you!